# insert into / select from ordered

Tags: sql-server-2008

I've a table like so:

```
create linkedList (
    id int identity(1, 1),
    parentId int not null, -- foreign key to table.id, always < this row's id
    name nvarchar(200)
)
```

I want to insert the rows from this table into:

```
create reportTable (
    id int,
    parentId int not null, -- foreign key to reportTable.id
    name nvarchar(200)
)
```

... but I only want to insert some rows (the exact where condition is not relevant), and I only want to to insert a row when its parent row was also inserted.

I can do this by using a cursor, but is there a better way? Basically I need an insert into / select from where I can control the insert order. If I understand ORDER BY on insert into it doesn't guarantee the order in which records are inserted (so I couldn't use an exists clause because I can't guarantee a parent row will be inserted before the child).

Basically I want something like:

```
INSERT INTO reportTable 
SELECT id, parentId, name
FROM linkedList
WHERE
    name = 'foo'
    and exists (select 1 from reportTable where id = linkedList.parentId)
OREDER BY id asc
```

... is there a shorthand way to do this that will guarantee the inserts are done from the lowest linkedList.Id to the highest (which is important due to the exists condition)?

Because the parent record may have a parent record, and that a parent record also, I can't just check in the exists clause if the parent record's name is foo, because any of the ancestors might fail to meet this requirement).

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a recursive CTE to expand the hierarchy from the child perspective (the anchor query in this case might include all records in the table, while the recursive portion would climb up the hierarchy to the root). This would give you the full ancestor hierarchy for every child. In theory, you could then write your `INSERT` using an `EXISTS` in the `WHERE` clause to filter the child records where one or more parents match your conditions.

https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/04/24/sql-server-introduction-to-hierarchical-query-using-a-recursive-cte-a-primer/

Keep in mind that expanding the hierarchy in this way can generate a very large amount of data. Depending on the size of your table, this might not be feasible.